# Excel SQL, Cast double query issue

Tags: sql, excel

I am trying to query two internal sheets within excel,
I want to use this following statement,

```
 cast('double', NULL) AS field1
```

When i remove the above line, my query works.

I get error `Method 'Execute' of object' _Connection' failed` . Double is the data type. The field should be null for now, but later a large number will be used in field1.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `isnull('double', NULL) AS field1` or `coalesce('double', NULL) AS field1`.

Comment: I guess 'double' is 'YourTable.Column'

Comment: No sorry, double is supposed to be the data type .

Comment: can you post part of your metod (foreach).have you tried with if else?